# DXA 1.5 compatible with 2013 SP1?

Tags: 2013-sp1, dxa, templating, dxa-1.5

DXA 1.5 for 2013 SP1 - the following docs (in the `readme.md`) have instructions to work for DXA 2013 SP1, but in the `.sln` from https://github.com/sdl/dxa-content-management doesnt build succesfully - even after following instructions below

[image]

Note that the `Sdl.Web.Tridion.Templates.csproj` project references CM assemblies in `_references` subdirectories which are not included in this repository, because these assemblies cannot be distributed without a signed license agreement. In order to build the project, the following CM assemblies will have to be obtained from an SDL Web/Tridion distribution and put in the appropriate `_references` subdirectories:

2013-sp1:

> Tridion.Common.dll
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Common.dll
>   Tridion.ContentManager.dll
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.dll
>   Tridion.ContentManager.TemplateTypes.dll
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.dll
>   Tridion.ContentManager.TypeRegistration.dll
>   Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.dll
>   Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.V2.dll
>   Tridion.Logging.dll

So the topology manager and lib's are referenced which is not compatible with 2013, only Web 8.

Is it possible to get direction on how to obtain a `.sln` specifically for DXA 1.5 (including the TBBs referenced above and on screenshot attached from DXA poc) so I can upload to my instance?

**UPDATE**

[image]

[image]

When I try to add assemblies here https://github.com/dd4t/DD4T.TridionTemplates/releases

> **2.0.8** 
>   If you're using SDL Tridion 2013 GA or SP1, please download DD4T.Templates.2.0.8.zip. If you're using SDL Tridion 2011, you should download DD4T.Templates.2.0.8-Legacy.zip.

I can upload the above, from ThijsBorst successfully.

**UPDATE #2**

PowerShell Error

[image]

This is the entire output when running the installer.

We are trying to import into one publication in an existing BluePrint and do not want to create dxa default hierarchy of publications.. but for any reason during the import it still refers to Publication 100 Master. (Screenshot above)

The items should be created only in the publication we specify by parameter `-masterPublication '070MultiProjectPublishDXA'` - correct?

`PS Drive:\Install\SDLT DXA\SDL DXA .NET 1.5\cms> & '.\cms-import.ps1' -importType master-only -masterPublication '070MultiProjectPublishDXA' -cmsUrl "http://MyInstanceUrl/"`

Comment: Why are you trying to build DD4T too? The build problem with TopologyManager.cs can be solved by either obtaining The TopologyManager reference DLLs (preferred) or by removing the reference and code using it in TopologyManager.cs; the code won't be executed on a 2013 SP1 system anyways.

Comment: Hey Rick, ultimately I'm just trying to build successfully, which I can't do bc I'm using references for 2013 sp1 and in the .sln for 1.5 references TP ootb.. Are the TP dlls contained in the cm-8.1 like Bart mentioned? If so, I'll raise a ticket today and see if I can get those.. otherwise I gotta go through the code like you said - which I didn't want to do, I just wanted to build and deploy, not customize

Comment: Yes, TTM DLLs can be obtained from Customer Support (like Bart mentioned). If you don't want to customize, why do you want to build? Why not use DXA's `cms-import.ps1` to get the TBBs (and all other CM items) in your Content Manager?

Comment: bc all I want are the DXA tbbs that recursively output json and if I use the ps script then it creates another branch on my bp and I don't want that if I chose to move these into higher env's

Comment: The DXA CMS import PowerShell script can also import the DXA items in an existing BluePrint using `-importType master-only -masterPublication $YourMasterPubTitle`. See the docs: http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v5/GUID-EDB49D8A-DCC3-45E7-B809-6A8B377C4FEA

Comment: @RickPannekoek so if I were to use the PowerShell script into an existing BluePrint publication called 030 Design Master would the command look like this? `PS Drive:\Install\SDLT DXA\SDL DXA .NET 1.5\cms> & '.\cms-import.ps1' -importType master-only -masterPublication $'030 Design Master' -cmsUrl "http://MyInstanceUrl/"`

Comment: Excluding the dollar sign.

Comment: This is the error I get: `An error occured while importing 'Drive:\Install\SDLT DXA\SDL DXA .NET 1.5\cms\2013sp1\master-only.zip'
At Drive:\Install\SDLT DXA\SDL DXA .NET 1.5\ImportExport\ContentManagerUtils.ps1:423 char:9
+         throw "An error occured while importing '$packageFullPath'"
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (An error occure...aster-only.zip':String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : An error occured while importing 'Drive:\Install\SDLT DXA\SDL DXA .NET 1.5\cms\2013sp1\master-only.zip'`

Comment: @RickPannekoek I have not been able to get the import working yet.. I can with the entire import, but not within an existing BluePrint..

Comment: Is there not more information in the output about what failed? Do you really have a PS drive called "Drive:" ?  Maybe that is the source of the problem? Try using a regular drive name.

Comment: @RickPannekoek added an update with screenshot on my post above..

Comment: Is the name of your root Structure Group "Home"? If not, you will have to specify your root SG name as a script parameter too (you may also have to specify the name of your BP Root Publication).

Comment: Brilliant! That worked! `PS E:\Install\SDLT DXA\SDL DXA .NET 1.5\cms> & '.\cms-import.ps1' -importType master-only -masterPublication 070MultiPro
jectPublishDXA -rootPublication "000 Empty Parent" -rootStructureGroup Root -cmsUrl "http://myInstanceUrl/"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is DXA 1.5 compatible with 2013 SP1, the simple answer is yes, as mentioned in the documentation http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v5/GUID-DD402008-D5C5-4DCA-A74F-893272D2B659

Since the TBBs for DXA 1.5 are made compatible with both 2013 SP1 and Web 8, you need to supply both the `2013-sp1` assemblies and `cm-8.1` assemblies in the appropriate `_references` subdirectories. This will build the TBBs as they are available in the current release (please note that when you want to manually rebuild the 1.5 TBBs, you should use the release branch, since the develop and master could contain changes for the upcoming 1.6 release already, so use https://github.com/sdl/dxa-content-management/tree/release/1.5).

The reason why these TBBs are build this way is to prevent us to have two separate solution files with different references and separate code for 2013 SP1 and Web 8 (it is a maintenance thing). We just build with all references in place and at runtime we determine if the code should be 2013 SP1 or Web 8 compatible, based on the CM version it is used in (actually based on the availibilty of the Web 8 specific APIs).

But unless you want to change the sources or debug the TBBs, then you don't really need to build the sources, you can find the TBBs in the import package of the DXA 1.5 distribution. All built and compatible for 2013 SP1 and Web 8.

Note: Don't use the tri sources anymore, they are DXA version 1.0 and will not be compatible with DXA 1.5.

Comment: Do you know where can I get "cm-8.1 assemblies in the appropriate _references subdirectories" from?

Comment: @AndrewWilliamRoss you can request the installation sources of Web 8 CU1 at Customer Support.

Comment: I have removed the topology manager references and am able to successfully build against 2013 assemblies.

Comment: Bart, so I ran the `import.ps1` script and it ships with these specific 2 tbbs `Generate dynamic component` & `Generate dynamic page` - that I wanted. But when I look at https://github.com/sdl/dxa-content-management/tree/release/1.5/Sdl.Web.Tridion.Templates/Templates/DD4T in the source code, I cant find the classes.. if I need to add additional logic to the tbbs.. ?